# distorted radar plot despite aspect ratio set to one

Tags: graph, stata

I am using a community-contributed command `radar` to make some plots. Most come out looking good, but occasionally I get ones that are squished even if I specify the aspect ratio to be 1.

Here's an example:

```
#delimit;

clear;
input str3 dow_str double weekly_mult;
"Sun" -16.491450926149962;
"Mon"  11.144192850866173;
"Tue"   9.387879945366835;
"Wen"   7.034146777677025;
"Thu"  5.4687468694060115;
"Fri" -3.5291081957540813;
"Sat"   -13.0144073214119;
end;

radar dow_str weekly_mult, aspect(1) xlab(, nogrid) legend(off) note("") name(g1, replace) nodraw;
radar dow_str weekly_mult, aspect(1) rlabel(-17(6)13) xlab(, nogrid)legend(off) note("") name(g2, replace) nodraw;
graph combine g1 g2, rows(1);
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this without specifying the labels manually each time?

Comment: Hard to know what's happening here.  I am not the author of `radar` as you know but I have programmed circular graphics and know that the trick is to use `twoway` but make whatever you don't want to see invisible. My only vague guess is that there is a .gph file here with invisible parts that are messing up the `graph combine`.  But that wouldn't really explain why the two graphs aren't aligned.

Comment: Typo time? Hereabouts we would abbreviate to Wed not Wen.

Comment: That said, `rlabel(-17(6)13)` is present in one case and not the other, and presumably you have reason to think that doesn't bite.

Comment: Good comments, @NickCox. I added the rlabel to patch things, but I have not figured out why it works. Are there any other implementations of this style of plot that I overlooked? Or any suggestions for how to find the invisible elements?

Comment: No white magic from me: I guess you need to look at the radar plot code to see what is made to show as background colour or to show as lines of zero width or length. There might be other tricks. To get a display that is exactly square you might specify four corner points but make them invisible too.